# How to setup a canadian CIBC bank account, from the US?

Tags: canada, banking, international, rent, university

I am an international student (US citizen currently residing in the US). I will be going to university in Toronto Canada in a couple of weeks. I have arranged to pay rent for a single room apartment, in order to do so I require a Canadian bank account. One which my father would be able to wire (transfer) funds to from the US. I was thinking CIBC, but I am not sure what the process is like in order to make it a Canadian account. **Can someone explain to me the process?**

Comment: Are you in one of the states where CIBC has a presence (Illinois, Michigan, Wyoming, Wisconsin)? If not, you should probably call CIBC. Or show up a bit early with cash and a cheque and open the account in Toronto directly.

Comment: I'm in DC: I see this one CIBC Private Wealth Management in DC. @JamesMcLeod

Comment: That’s probably not a location that does retail banking, but they may be able to connect you with the right people.

Comment: @JamesMcLeod do u know of a different Canadian bank that has locations in Washington DC or near?

Comment: @JamesMcLeod perhaps bmo harris?

Comment: I am in Toronto; not too familiar with the US banking scene. We have an oligopoly of 6 major banks, so it should be easy to find the closest to you by process of elimination. RBC Bank has branches in Annapolis and Baltimore and (a bit further from DC) Richmond. https://www.rbccm.com/en/offices/united-states.page